# Why is Alt ignored when using "action.SendKeys(Keys.Alt + "l").Perform();"?

Tags: c#, selenium, sendkeys

I have looked all over and keep seeing the same basic "solutions" none of which seem to work for my problem. The purpose of this is to use a hotkey to make a popup window display. (Works fine manually). Is there some other way to force an Alt? Perhaps something special you need to do before trying to press hotkey combinations? This is using C# in Selenium.

Here is a list of some of the ways I have tried to make it work.

```
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%l");

        claimMap.UIEditServiceDate.SendKeys("%l");

        claimMap.SendKeys("%l");

        action.SendKeys(Keys.Alt + "l");

        action.SendKeys("%(l)");

        action.Build().Perform();
        action.SendKeys(Keys.Alt + "l");

        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(Keys.LeftAlt + "l");

        action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys("l").Perform();

        action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys("l").Build().Perform();

        action.SendKeys(Keys.Alt + "l").Perform();

        action.SendKeys("%l").Perform();
```

Comment: maybe try sending keys to an actual `IWebElement`? I think maybe `claimMap` is an element, so `claimMap.SendKeys(Keys.Alt + "l")` right now I'm not sure what the type is for most of your examples

Comment: Erm, wait, is it Alt+L or Alt+I?  What window has the focus when you send it?

Comment: Is this code running on your PC or on a Node? If it is running on a Node, does that Node have a different OS than your PC? I had a similar the issue, which I solved by changing the Shortcut to use the correct keys depending on the current running OS.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the actual written statements to call these keys.

```
// Single keys:
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") // For enter
SendKeys.Send("{%}") // For Alt
SendKeys.Send("{^}") // For Ctrl
SendKeys.Send("{+}") // For shift

// Combination keys:
SendKeys.Send("%(l)") // For Alt-l
```